# Is it possible to have a single Google drive account where many users can upload files to from an application?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Let's say I own 'mainAccount@gmail.com'. Now I create an application(not using a service account) that uses one time authorization to get a refresh token. Then it stores that refresh token in a database.

Next I let other users(anonymous visitors for example) use my application to upload files to my google drive storage. Every time a user wants to upload, the stored refresh token is used to get an access token(to authorize the upload of the user that is not authenticated or might not even have a gmail account).

I am curious as to how does Drive API interpret this sort of request? Especially when there are hundreds of users uploading files. Would I be hitting any quota limitations? I assume the API thinks 1 gmail account = 1 user not 100 users or more.

Comment: Just curious, is there any way you would be willing to share how you accomplished this. I am trying to figure out how to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quota limit is based upon the number of requests being sent not which account its being requested against or which refresh token is doing the sending.

[image]

The only quota I think may cause you a problem is the requests per second quota.  You are allowed 100 req/sec if you don't set quota user this is set by the IP address.  So if this is running though your website you are only going to be able to send 100 Requests a second.  If you randomized quota user. (No I am not sure how to send quota user in JavaScript you will need to look that up) that would remove this problem.

+1 for being the first person I have seen that figured out how to get around the no service account issue with JavaScript :)

Comment: Adding a randomized quotaUser parameter to the requests did the job. No longer hitting any limitation.

Comment: That's what I do as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not conceptually different from you being logged on to multiple PCs, or having an app which say syncs between a web app and multiple devices.

The quota issue isn't well defined, so it's a bit of a guess whether or not you'll hit the Per User Quota, or even the undocumented bucket quota. The former can be increased by request, the latter can't.

If you do hit limits, you have two levels of workaround:-

1. Create multiple apps within your project, and somehow allocate or round-robin access tokens from multiple stored refresh tokens
2. Go a step further and create multiple projects. This of course creates a possible permission/sharing issue so you would either need to have Drive scope (a bad idea if this is a general purpose Drive account), or make sure that each user was always bound to the same refresh token.

btw, you understand the potential security issues with multiple users being able to use the access token to access each others' files?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Google sees all the requests coming from your registered application in the developer console and not from any user. The destination Drive account is just a destination for the file.

That's possible just as you described it. Get an access token with the refresh token stored somewhere and upload a file with that access token from any user anywhere to a single drive.

The quota limits are monstrous and the single Drive folder would get full before you would be hitting the quota.

Comment: I generally agree, but the token bucket quota is really quite small, around 30 in my experience. I'm pretty sure this quota is somehow linked to the session, but can't be sure. If it's linked to the user, the client-id or the project, it could be an issue.